# Android ffmpeg apply video effects take time

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-editing

I am using below command to apply effect,its take 6-8 minutes to apply effect for 2min video.
Please help me to improve effective time for ffmpeg commands.

```
String commandStr = "ffmpeg -y -i "
            + mVideoData.getPath()
            + " -strict experimental -vf curves=vintage -s 640x480 -r 30 -aspect 4:3 -ab 48000 -ac 2 -ar 22050 -b 2097k -vcodec mpeg4 /sdcard/videokit/curve.mp4";
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Remember that you're working on a phone.

These are not CPU workhorses—they're just phones, built for running a long time on little amounts of battery. The `curves` filter is quite resource-intensive, as it calculates a new value for every single pixel, for every single frame in your input video. The video encoder itself probably won't be the bottleneck here.

Effects on videos are better rendered not on the phone itself, but some beefy web server. On the phone you might want to run the effect on a preview clip first, or just a still image.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I completely agree with @slhck. You have to understand the limitation of mobile computing. But still to satisfy you here you can give a try to these.

Include `-preset ultrafast` option. It reduces time a lot but sacrifices quality. I ran your command with this for a `4 min.` video and it took 3-4 min to complete.

```
String commandStr = "ffmpeg -y -i "
        + mVideoData.getPath()
        + " -strict experimental -vf curves=vintage -s 640x480 -r 30 -aspect 4:3 -ab 48000 -ac 2 -ar 22050 -b 2097k -preset ultrafast /sdcard/videokit/curve.mp4";
```

Next you can reduce the `audio bitrate` and remove `audio sampling` rate too. If possible also reduce `framerate`. All these can collectively reduce your time.

Hope this helps you.Cheers.:)

Comment: thanks for reply.
Used above command but there no any kind of time improvement.

Comment: Well I have already tried; but you have to see the overall result(for all file sizes).

Comment: Note that the OP used the mpeg4 encoder and your command uses x264. Using x264 makes the whole thing run longer again, even with the ultrafast preset. Perhaps one could try encoding to MJPEG or losslessly to see how long the filtering itself takes (cc @PrvN)

Answer (score -1):

per seconds image create Video

```
commandStr = "ffmpeg -framerate 1/1 -i " + privatePath + "img_%d.jpg -strict experimental -vf curves=vintage -s 640x480 -r 10 -aspect 4:3 -ab 48000 -ac 2 -ar 22050 -b 2097k -preset ultrafast "+privatePath+ "Video.mp4";
```